# What is the use case of a ResourceSubscriber's add method?

Tags: rx-java

I could not figure out the use case of a ResourceSubscriber's `add(Disposable)` method.

I thought that the `add(Disposable)` method might be used for disposing multiple disposables.

However, if I want to dispose some subscriptions together, 
I would use a CompositeSubscription and add Disposables from the return value of the `subscribeWith` method.
Moreover, this way is easier to read, I guess.

Also, I thought that, when the main flowable were completed, the additional flowable might be disposed automatically because a completed flowable might be thougt as the disposed flowable.
So, I tried bellow.

```
Flowable<Long> f1 = Flowable.interval(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).take(3);
Flowable<Long> f2 = Flowable.interval(200L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

ResourceSubscriber<Long> s = new ResourceSubscriber<Long>() {
  ...
};

s.add(f2.subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<Long>() {
  ...
}));

f1.subscribe(s);
```

However, `f2` kept working after `f1` was completed.
`f2` was not disposed.

Now, I wonder what would be the good use case of a ResourceSubscriber's `add(Disposable)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResourceSubscriber` allows you to register `Disposable` resources similar how 1.x `Subscriber` allowed it and is there to ease the transition from 1.x to 2.x. However, it only tracks the resources and you have to manually call `dispose` in your `onError` and `onComplete` implementation to dispose those resources.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Now, I understand the usage. I tried the similar code in 1.x which doesn't call `unsubscribe()` in `onCompleted` but the added Subscription was unsubscribed when main Subscription was completed. Then, I added `dispose()` in `onCompele()` in 2.0 code and the result was that the added Subscription was disposed.

Comment: In 1.x, almost all Subscribers gets wrapped into a `SafeSubscriber` which calls unsubscribe on your Subscriber. We don't do this by default in 2.x saving a lot of overhead in the entire library.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Since the reason was the performance matter, the change is understandable.  Maybe, it might be a good pracrice that `dispose` were called in `onComplete` and  `onError` when users used ResourceSubscription's `add(Disposable)`.